# C++: Making method return the same object every time

Tags: c++, opengl, static, static-methods

I would like to have a function that loads a file (in this case an OpenGL texture), but only actually loads the file once, and every time it is called after that it just returns what it initially loaded.

What would be a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some place to store that state. That can be either inside an object or as a static variable. Let's say:

```
class TextureLoader {
public:
    TextureLoader() {}
    GLuint loadTexture(std::string const & filename){
        std::map<std::string, GLuint>::iterator it = m_loadedTextures.find(filename);
        if(it == m_loadedTextures.end()){
            GLuint id = load(filename);
            m_loadedTextures[filename] = id;
            return id;
        }
        else{
            return it->second;
        }
    }
    ~TextureLoader(){
        // iterate and delete textures
    }
private:
    GLuint load(std::string const & filename){
        // real loading
    }
    std::map<std::string, GLuint> m_loadedTextures;
};
```

Comment: this seems good, but some commenting would make this more easily understandable...

Comment: and what do you think of using a static `std::map` in the method, instead of creating a class?

Comment: @Jay: tibur's method is much better since creating a class in this way is inherently thread safe so long as you create the TextureLoader instance locally in each thread.  Moreover, you can have more than one TextureLoader in use in your program at the same time.  If the state is a static variable then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to have a static map inside the function that associates the parameters to the function (here, the filename) with a pointer to the unique value it returns.  You can then have the function check whether the map contains the input and, if so, hand back the texture associated with it.  Otherwise, you can then do the load, store the result in the map, and hand back the result.  For example:

```
Texture* LoadTexture(const std::string& filename) {
    static std::map<std::string, Texture*> previousResults;

    /* Look up existing value. */
    Texture* result = previousResults[filename];

    /* If this doesn't exist, then go create it and pretend it was there all along. */
    if (result == NULL)
        result = previousResults[filename] = ActuallyLoadTexture(filename);

    /* Hand back the cached result. */
    return result;
}
```

If you do this, you should be careful about thread-safety, since multiple calls to the function could cause problems with the map.  Syncrhonize as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are looking for is an implementation of the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) Design Pattern.

There are a variety of ways to implement this, and now that you know what it is called, you can decide what method is best. Your first stop could be a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=singleton+c%2B%2B) of this site for other similar questions.

Comment: A singleton per texture file sounds almost certainly wrong, and at the very least hard to manage. In the most basic form of a singleton, it would involve a class per texture file, which is not nicely maintainable. In more complex forms, it really ceases to be a singleton.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I don't think he meant a singleton per texture file. For reference imagine he applied the Singleton pattern to tibur's answer.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: OK, that makes sense; the resultant factory could be a singleton. Though its being a singleton doesn't single-handedly solve the original problem. :)

Comment: Avoid singletons where singletons are not needed ... yes it could be a singleton but there is no reason to only have one texture loader and the scope of a texture loader does not need to be global.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would either associate with a map or unordered_map filepaths to Texture*s.

```
class render_state {
    std::map<std::string, Texture> textures;
    Texture* load_texture(std::string filepath) {
        if (textures.find(filepath) != textures.end()) {
            return &textures[filepath];
        }
        // load the texture here if it's not in cache
    }
    // Other rendering methods and state here.
};
```

But now, you have another problem, which is that sometimes you might use a relative filepath, or sometimes, an absolute filepath. Also, in some libraries, they can accept varying versions of newlines and backslashes or forward slashes. What if I loaded a Texture, then only used it for a specific time and didn't need it again? Whoops, memory leak.

The best thing to do is just return a Texture object (or (possibly smart) pointer to such) and let the user worry about managing it. If someone creates a resource, it's *their* job to manage it, not yours.

Comment: normally this might be a good solution, but OpenGL works a little differently. you load the textures and OpenGL handles them. and the load texture function would just return a texture ID.

Comment: @Jay: So your class Texture handles all the OGL specifics and presents an abstraction, and you return a pointer to that. So what's different to doing under Direct3D, or indeed, Direct2D or GDI or any other rendering technology? Resources are managed by those who requested their creation- and it doesn't matter how those resources are implemented.

Comment: don't get me wrong, this was a good answer. however, because of OpenGL, I would rather do something more like @tibur's answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [boost::flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html). It does pretty much what you want. Load objects avoiding duplicates.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `boost::flyweight` is header-only, and you should certainly already have Boost in your development environment. The rest of the world does!

Comment: while boost is a great library using a library because it's popular is not a good reason ... for a 3d application performance is key and extra dependencies and bloat are factors.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be what you are looking for:

```
Texture& loadTexture(cosnt std::string& texture)
{
    // Store all loaded data here
    // Each file maps to a loded texture object
    static boost::ptr_map<std::string, Texture>   data;

    boost::ptr_map<std::string, Texture>::iterator find = data.find(texture);
    if (find == data.end())
    {
        // If it is not in the structure then load it this one time
        find = data.insert(texture, doLoad(texture));
    }

    // return a reference to the texture
    return *(find->second);
}
```

Comment: why use boost::ptr_map instead of std::map?

Comment: Because it allows derivation in Texture. std::map will not allow polymorphism in the objects that implement texture unless you store pointers in which case you need to delete them in the destructor (using boost::ptr_map just makes that easier). If you don't need polymorphism then std::map is just fine.