# Accessing std::map keys and values

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stdvector, stdmap

How do you access an `std::vector` of the keys or values of an `std::map`?

Thanks.

Edit: I would like to access the actual elements, not just copies of their contents. essentially I want a reference, not a copy.

This is essentially what I am wanting to do:

```
std::map<std::string, GLuint> textures_map;

// fill map

glGenTextures( textures_map.size(), &textures_map.access_values_somehow[0] );
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to use a std::map instead of a std::vector?  glGenTextures wants a pointer to an array of GLuint as the second parameter you could create your own texture pool object with methods that provide both a way to search an internal map as well as what is needed for OpenGL calls ...

Comment: @AJG85 yes, I am storing a file name with the texture ID, so that I don't reload a texture that has already been loaded. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589543/c-making-method-return-the-same-object-every-time

Comment: Just saying there is more than one way to skin a cat ... you could keep a map of hash keys to filenames where to determine whether to load a texture into a vector of GLuint in a class where the hash is based off filename and vector position or something along that lines. Your problem is not trying to get a vector of map values your problem is designing a texture pool ... think of the big picture not the step.

Comment: @AJG85 hmm... could you elaborate on that solution in the question I linked to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said in their answers, you can't access all the keys or values in the form of a std::vector without copying them - std::map isn't designed for this form of access.

For your situation, I would set up 2 containers:

```
std::vector<GLuint> texture_id;
std::map<std::string, size_t> texture_map;
```

where the vector stores the ID, and the map's value is the index to the ID in the vector.  When you add a new texture, add the ID into the vector with `push_back()`, whose index is stored in a map entry with the last element's index, e.g.:

```
pair<map<string, size_t>::iterator, bool> result = 
    texture_map.insert(make_pair(new_texture_name, -1));    //ignore the index for now
if(result.second) { //true when the texture name isn't already in the map
    texture_id.push_back(new_id);
    result.first->second = texture_id.size()-1; //update the index in the map to this ID's element in texture_id
}
```

The push_back would maintain the same indexes for old IDs.  Encapsulate all this within a class with functions to add and search for textures, just like in the answer to your other question.

This would let you call, after the IDs are loaded:

```
glGenTextures( textures_id.size(), &(textures_id[0]) );
```

... since std::vector guarantees that elements are consecutive to one another in memory.

---

edit: changed the map's value type; this was previously GLuint*, pointing at the vector's elements. Thanks to Oli Charlesworth for pointing out this design's flaw.
edit: added sample code

Comment: -1: Be very careful.  If the vector ever gets resized (which will happen a lot if you don't reserve a max capacity before pushing elements into it), then all your pointers will become invalidated.  (I'll remove the downvote if you address this issue in your answer...)

Comment: excellent point, Oli.  I've updated the map's value type to indicate the vector index; this will avoid the invalidation problem.

Comment: @martin_ljchan could you give sample code for this: "then add a map entry with the last element's index (eg. texture_id.size()-1 )" thanks!

Comment: I've replaced the hand-wavey description with sample code. Hope this makes more sense : )

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that because neither the values nor the keys are laid out consecutively in memory. Each key/value pair is allocated independently in memory. In a situation like yours, you *have to* copy the values around.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single function you can call to get all of the keys or values from an STL map.  Instead, you can use the map iterators to access this information:

```
for (map<K, V>::iterator itr = myMap.begin(); itr != myMap.end(); ++itr) {
    // Access key as itr->first
    // Access value as itr->second
}
```

If you want to write a function that takes these values and wraps them up in an STL vector, then you could do so like this:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
std::vector<K> GetKeys(const std::map<K, V>& m) {
    std::vector<K> result;
    result.reserve(m.size()); // For efficiency

    for (typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); ++itr)
         result.push_back(itr->first);

    return result;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
std::vector<V> GetValues(const std::map<K, V>& m) {
    std::vector<V> result;
    result.reserve(m.size()); // For efficiency

    for (typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); ++itr)
         result.push_back(itr->second);

    return result;
}
```

Note that in these template functions, the type of the iterator is

```
typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator
```

instead of

```
std::map<K, V>::const_iterator
```

This is because `const_iterator` here is a *dependent type* - a type that depends on a template argument - and consequently for silly historical reasons must be prefaced by the `typename` keyword.  There's a good explanation of this [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I remember reading about it somewhere before (and since forgotten), but can you please explain the purpose of the `typename` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @dreamlax- Updated to address your question.  Let me know if this is still confusing.

Comment: @templatetypedef this solution would work, except I want to access a reference to the map keys/values, instead of just getting a copy of it. I should have made my question more clear, I have now edited it...

Comment: you can still use this, but change the return type to `std::vector<K&>`.  It is now a vector of references.  But be aware:  your references could be invalidated if you insert into the map (or remove from it).

Comment: This won't work in the context of this question, though, since the OpenGL call assumes it's looking at a contiguous block of memory holding the actual values, and if you have a vector of references you'll end up with a block of memory holding pointers to those values.

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with OpenGL.  +1 for the link you provided though - useful info about typename.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what others have said, it sounds very much like you really want to put the values into a `std::vector` and then sort the vector; that way you can access the contents like you want to (i.e. via a pointer to a contiguous array of them).

Note that this assumes that reading will be your bottleneck, and that writing (i.e. setting up the vector) will be done relatively infrequently.  If not, then you're probably better off sticking with the `std::map`, and then copying the contents into a temporary array/vector every time you want to use them in this fashion.

Comment: no, I don't need to sort anything. the only reason I am using is a map is so that I can search for a filename, and if it is there, then get the corresponding texture ID, and if it is not there, then load the texture. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589543/c-making-method-return-the-same-object-every-time

Comment: @Jay: In which case, if read speed is essential, then I'd still consider storing it as a vector, and also using a separate `std::map` to map keys to indices into the vector (you could use iterators/pointers instead of indices if you're sure the vector capacity never needs to change).